# How to render postgresql results in ejs using node pg?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, ejs

I'm new to node/express/postgres and trying to build a simple todo application. I'm trying to render a view using an ejs file, but instead of displaying the query results, the page is displaying the query itself:

```
(request, response) => { pool.query('SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => { if (error) { throw error } response.status(200).json(results.rows) }) }
```

I'm generating the queries in a queries.js file:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
    user: '*',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'todo',
    password: '*',
    port: 5432,
})

const getAllItems = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
}

module.exports = {
    getAllItems
}
```

And calling it in the app.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const db = require('./queries');

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var todoDbList = db.getAllItems;
var itemNames = db.getAllItemNames;

//All todo information
app.get('/items',function(req, res) {
    res.render("allItemInfo.ejs", {
        todoDbList: db.getAllItems
        });
});
```

Then rendering in an EJS file:

```
<body>
   <div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>
   <div><%= todoDbList %> </div>
</body>
```

What am I missing here to see the query results in the div and not the query itself?

Comment: Don't pass `todoDbList: db.getAllItems` - that will render the function. You want to *call* the function, and instead of doing `response.json(…)`, do `response.render(…)` the rows.

Comment: @Bergi I updated the route to call the function `todoDbList: db.getAllItems()` and changed the query function to `.render(results.rows)`. This gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined` from the line in my queries file `response.status(200).render(results.rows)`.

Comment: Are you passing arguments to your function? You declared it with parameters.

Comment: @Bergi I see where I declared the request and response parameters in the queries.js, but I'm not sure what to pass when calling the function in my app.js. Do I need to have an `app.get` request nested within the request that renders the ejs?

Comment: Yes, you get `req` and `res` from the `app.get` as arguments to your callback, and you can pass them down into `getAllItems`.

Comment: How do I get the req and the res? Say I include `let theData = req.get('/itemstst',db.getAllItems);` is there a way to get it from there?

Comment: They're passed as arguments to that callback function, yes!

Comment: @Bergi I'm still not understanding how to get the data using the `getAllItems` function. I can get the desired result by putting the query in a GET request inside of my app.js file, but I'm not sure if it is best practice to have all the queries in a file like I had, or include them in app.js like this `app.get('/todos', function(req, res) {
 const sql = 'SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC';
 pool.query(sql, [], (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
   return console.log(err.message);
  }
  res.render("allItemInfo.ejs", {todoDbList: result.rows})
 })
});`

Comment: Yes, that should work (except for the error handling). Now you can either name that complete `function(req, res) { … }` function and import it from a different module before passing it to `app.get(…)`, or you can refactor various parts of it into helper functions (which you then can put in another module).

Comment: For writing helper functions, get familiar with how to write functions that accept callbacks themselves, or even better, how to use promises.

Comment: @Bergi I'll definitely go look into both...thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone else has a similar question.

Reconfigured the getAllItems function in the queries.js file to render the .ejs file and pass in the query results

```
const getAllItems = function(req, res) {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC';
    pool.query(sql, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        res.render("allItemInfo.ejs", {todoDbList: results.rows})
    })
};
```

Call the function in the app.js file

```
//all todo information
app.get('/todos', db.getAllItems);
```