# Node.js postgreSQL integration - TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeerror

I am trying to implement a simple postgresql / Node.JS site however, I am coming across a TypeError with regards to the res object in the query.js file, when performing the query in postgreSQL to insert into a webpage.

I have created a  route/users.js file which renders the site and specifies the 'user' variable as such:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const db = require('../../config/queries');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) =>
  res.render('users', {
    users: db.getUsers
  })
);

module.exports = router;
```

Then I have a config/queries.js file which performs the query and returns the result to the above file:

```
const pool = require('./db');

const getUsers = (req, res) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    console.log(results.rows);
    res.status(200).json(results.rows);
  });
};

module.exports = {
  getUsers
};
```

Finally the html site is written as such:

```
<p> Hello world</p>
<ul> {{users}} 99999 </ul>
```

When I load the page localhost:5000/users, whilst the console is logging the user data correctly, the following error occurs
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`
and the page displays:

> Hello world
>
> 99999

It appears the error occurs because the res in res.status(200).json(results.rows) is not defined though I don't know why that would be the case.

Many thanks!

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277144/how-to-render-postgresql-results-in-ejs-using-node-pg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code to get results of the query and then try to render the page.
*getUsers* will not return the results immediately but in a callback.
So a correct version maybe like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) =>

   getUsers((error,result)=>
   {
      if (error) {
          throw error;
      }
      console.log(results.rows);
      res.render('users', {
        users: results.rows
       })
   })
);
```

---

```
const getUsers = (callback) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC',callback )
};
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the purpose of "const getUsers = (callback)" ? Beginner question but will help my understanding.

Comment: @ewldh20 it is defining a function getUsers which takes a callback as parameter. it passes that callback to the postgresql , so that when the results are fetched from database the callback is called.