# Cannot read property 'notifies' of undefined in PostgreSQL Getting this error

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I am trying to run the below query

```
Select hcfd.*,hhd.pic
From hr.lob_candidate_feed_details as hcfd
Left Join hr.lob_hr_details as hhd
On hcfd.hr_id=hhd.id
```

for this query i am getting this error
Cannot read property 'notifies' of undefined

I am getting it only when i am trying to get hhd.pic column from the hr.lob_hr_details thus table

So,Any one please help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Node.JS error, check out:

[Node.js postgreSQL integration - TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337465/node-js-postgresql-integration-typeerror-cannot-read-property-status-of-und)

Greetings, Alejandro